# SELECT multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help here,

```
table "friends"
+------+-------------+-----------+
   id  |  friend_id  |   user_id |
+------+-------------+-----------+
   1   |    1222     |   99999   |
+------+-------------+-----------+
   2   |   48989     |   1492    |
+------+-------------+-----------+

table "users"
+------+-------------+---------------+
   id  |  user_name  |   user_image  | 
+------+-------------+---------------+
 99999 |     Mark    | img/abc.jpg   |
+------+-------------+---------------+
 1222  |     Tom     | img/xyz.jpg   |
+------+-------------+---------------+
 etc.  |    etc.     |       etc..   |
+------+-------------+---------------+
```

i want SELECT table friends and make WHERE statement :

etc : ... WHERE user_id=$_SESSION[user_id] ...
and will display data from table users

ok , let say :
my current id is 99999  so in table friends is match only 1222 , so this will display all data(image,etc..) from id 1222(Tom) from table users.

So my question here is how i need to write this code for generate users data ?

*i try to use UNION and LEFT JOIN..but no luck..still newbie..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
$friends_of_user = mysql_query('
SELECT 
   f.*, u.* 
FROM  
    friends f 
  LEFT JOIN 
      users u 
  ON 
      u.id = f.friend_id
WHERE 
      f.user_id = '.$user_id);
```

and to exclude all users which doesn't have profiles in users table, just change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`

Comment: @ruslyrossi, Use inner join if you want eliminate users without friends.

Comment: @Johan: probably incorrect. LEFT JOIN in this case means that all friends which doesn't have profile will be shown as NULL

Comment: Hmm You'd need to do `select whatever from users u inner join friends f on ....` in my head that's what you did.

Comment: @genesis: so now if i follow your code i can list data from table users, if my current id is macth with friend_id in table friends?

Comment: @ruslyrossi: this query will select all friends and their profiles

Comment: @ruslyrossi: `if my current id is macth ` look at my edit. You'll have to specify YOUR_USERID to get his/her friends and their profiles

Comment: @Johan: this query (edited) selects all friends of user YOUR_USERID and their profiles. If user is deleted, friend data will be NULL. If I'd use INNER JOIN it would delete all friends with no profiles (deleted profiles

Comment: This code only works if `$_SESSION['user_id]` is an int. `mysql_real_escape_string()` always works. That's why I'm not a fan of the intval trick.

Comment: @Johan: Tell me, why you'd use "id" for a string?

Comment: @ruslyrossi: Yes, but don't use mysql_Real_escape_string unless you put $user_id into quotes.

Comment: @genesis-φ, it's like what I tell my wife when we're on holiday: "expectations will ruin your day". Just because a field is named `id` and sane people would expect it to be an int does not make it true (or even likely).

Comment: actually..i not understand what both statement mean?

Comment: @ruslyrossi: Well, mysql_real_escape_string() shouldn't be used without quotes. It is dangerous. intval() caould be used without quotes

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the following code:

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']);
$sql = "SELECT f.* 
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN friends f ON (u.user_id = f.friend_id)
        WHERE u.user_id = '$user_id' ";
```